# Regex match all spaces except those at the end of a string

Tags: regex

On a keyup event in a text input field, I'm trying to replace any spaces with a hyphen, provided there follows another character; basically changing all spaces except for trailing spaces:

```
$('#id').val().replace(/ /g, '-');  // Currently targets *all* spaces
```

[According to regexr](http://www.regexr.com/3a9mh), the following should work:

```
/[ ](?!\s)/g
```

But it doesn't work in practise, as evidenced by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/g62hkj4d/).

What's the right approach to this problem, and why does regexr give me a false positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `$` inside the negative lookahead.

```
\s(?!$)
```

OR

```
 (?!$)
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you. Any idea why regexr behaves as it does?

Comment: @verism regexr failed to open for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just capture trailing spaces and then attach it at last

```
$('#id').val(function(_,val){
    var trailSpaces = val.match(/\s+$/g)[0];
    return val.replace(/ /g,"-") + trailSpaces;
});
```